# How to secure your backend API to be exposed to your frontend calls and nothing else?

Tags: security, frontend

I have built my frontend on React JS and Backend on Fast API (Python). I do a google oAuth login after which I lazy load the pages on the browser. What I am concerned about is that once someone succeeds google oAuth then they can perform other operations and inspect the requests to see how the backend API is working. (I am parsing an APIKey into the Authorization header of the request body).

My concern is that if someone logs in through google oAuth and inspects the networking tab:

[image]

They can view all the content and then be able to make API calls on their own and do any malicious operations. Is there a way to encrypt the Authorization header so that the user could not get access to my backend API?

Comment: I just wonder if a encryption would help in this case. Enrypted or not, they just need the value inside the auhtorization header. Could it be better to have a signed JWT with a role, which then authorizes/restrict the access to the API to the needed interfaces with the set role inside the JWT?

Comment: This sounds like a solution (with lots of other setup to facilitate role-based authentications and so on), though first I would want to ensure that there's no way to utilize something that can hide or show some gibberish code in those headers>